# Android ndk-gdb error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I use android-sdk-r12m-r17m-linux.zip and android-ndk-r8-linux-x86.tar.bz2 to compile my android apk.

My compiling steps are:

```
   android update project -p . --target 2
   ndk-build APP_ABI=mips
   ant debug
```

The output apk works well on my mips platform.
However, after I try ndk-gdb, I get the following error.

```
   ERROR: The device does not support the application's targetted CPU ABIs!
   Device supports:  mips
   Package supports: armeabi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndk-gdb` reads `APP_ABI` from `Application.mk` file. Because you are passing `APP_ABI` on commandline and you probably have emptry `Application.mk` file, it assumes `APP_ABI` has default value armeabi.

Try creating `Application.mk` file and write inside `APP_ABI := mips`